# getting serialized object in ajax query to web server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I'm new to web development, so in order to test some things I've created an empty ASP.NET project with a web api. I've written the following controller and javascript files:
**Controller:**

```
 namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
    {
        public class PairController : ApiController
        {
            public Point Get([FromUri]int rows, [FromUri]int cols)
            {
                return new Point(rows, cols);
            }
        }
    }
```

**JS:**

```
var api = 'api/Pair';
var question = '/?rows=' + $('#rows').val() + '&cols=' + $('#cols').val();
var url = api + question;
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    alert('success');
    console.log(data[0].X + ' ' + data[0].Y);
}).fail(function () {
    alert('error!');
});
```

When I looked in the console, I see two ''undefined'' lines. 
I was expecting to see the values from the rows and cols input fields.
Why is that? My understanding is that in the server side, the web server sees that the client expects an answer in json format, so it serializes the point to json, and sends in the answer:

```
{
     "X": rows input value,
     "Y": cols input value,
     "IsEmpty": something 
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(data.X + ' ' + data.Y);`

Comment: Tried, still undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you write `data[0].X`, you try to access to the first item of an array. But on back-end side you are not returning an Array of Point (`List<Point>`) but a Point. So it's serailized as an object which correspond to

```
{
     "X": rows input value,
     "Y": cols input value,
     "IsEmpty": something 
}
```